# Control in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a control in visual studio that will allow me to add controls in a list view format, like this one in Access where I can add buttons etc:

[image: A screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView or an ItemsControl and edit its item template to fit your needs.